# vuejs treeselect - delay loading does not work via vuex action

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, vuex

Using [Vue TreeSelect Plugin](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#delayed-loading) to load a nested list of nodes from firebase backend. It's doc page says,

> It's also possible to have root level options to be delayed loaded. If no options have been initially registered (options: null), vue-treeselect will attempt to load root options by calling loadOptions({ action, callback, instanceId }).

`loadOptions` (in my App.vue) dispatch vuex `action_FolderNodesList`, fetches (from firebase) formats (as required by vue-treeselect), and mutates the state `folder_NodesList`, then tries to update options `this.options = this.get_FolderNodesList` but this does not seems to work.

Here is the `loadOptions` method (in app.vue)

```
loadOptions() {
      let getFolderListPromise = this.$store.dispatch("action_FolderNodesList");
      getFolderListPromise.then(_ => {
        this.options = this.get_FolderNodesList;
      });
    }
```

Vue errors out with `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got String with value ""`

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, why that does not work. A working [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-treeselect-nrizu)

### Source

#### App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-7">
                <div class="field">
                    <Treeselect 
                      :multiple="true" 
                      :options="options" 
                      :load-options="loadOptions" 
                      :auto-load-root-options="false" 
                       placeholder="Select your favourite(s)..." 
                       v-model="value" />
                    <pre>{{ get_FolderNodesList }}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

import Treeselect from "@riophae/vue-treeselect";
import "@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.css";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            value: null,
            options: null,
            called: false
        };
    },
    components: {
        Treeselect
    },
    computed: mapGetters(["get_FolderNodesList"]),

    methods: {
        loadOptions() {
            let getFolderListPromise = this.$store.dispatch("action_FolderNodesList");
            getFolderListPromise.then(_ => {
                this.options = this.get_FolderNodesList;
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

#### Store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    folder_NodesList: ""
  },

  getters: {
    get_FolderNodesList(state) {
      return state.folder_NodesList;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    mutate_FolderNodesList(state, payload) {
      state.folder_NodesList = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    action_FolderNodesList({ commit }) {
      fmRef.once("value", snap => {
        var testObj = snap.val();

        var result = Object.keys(testObj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
          acc.push({
            id: cur,
            label: cur,
            children: recurseList(testObj[cur])
          });
          return acc;
        }, []);
        commit("mutate_FolderNodesList", result);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I've been struggling to find proper example of using api data and treeview/select.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are calling `this.options` which would update the entire element while only the current expanding option should be updated.

It seems `loadOptions()` is called with some arguments that you can use to update only the current childnode. The first argument seems to contain all the required assets so I wrote my `loadTreeOptions` function like this:

```
loadTreeOptions(node) {
            // On initial load, I set the 'children' to NULL for nodes to contain children
            // but inserted an 'action' string with an URL to retrieve the children
            axios.get(node.parentNode.action).then(response => {
                // Update current node's children
                node.parentNode.children = response.data.children;
                // notify tree to update structure
                node.callback();
            }).catch(
                errors => this.onFail(errors.response.data)
            );
        },
```

Then I set `:load-options="loadTreeOptions"` on the `<vue-treeselect>` element on the page. Maybe you were only missing the `callback()` call which updates the structure. My installation seems simpler than yours but it works properly now.